# Finding a random element within an element within a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
        $stmt = $web_dbi->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();  
        $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;   

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          $results[] = $row;
        }

        $randomNumber = mt_rand(0,($num_of_rows-1));
        if($results[$randomNumber]['mysql_field']==anothervalue){
        ...
```

how do I access, at random, a given element of `$results[]`? Is this syntax correct in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. I personally prefer using [array_rand](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to select a random element from the array:

```
$random_value = $results[array_rand($results)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
shuffle($results);
$item_to_use = array_pop ($results);
```

Not the most efficient but uses fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Alternativley, you can use sql query to get random result.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND()
```

Or to get random array element from PHP array try this,

```
echo $results[mt_rand(0, $num_of_rows - 1)]['mysql_field'];
```